# Mongo DB freezes during --config or --dbpath

Tags: mongodb, command-prompt

(I am a Windows user)
I recently installed the MongoDB application onto a remote HDD. I have installed Mongo DB before on my Laptop's SDD and it worked perfectly. I am encountering an issue with the `mongod --config "PATH to cfg file"` command and the `mongod --dbpath "PATH to database"`. When I run either command, the program halts (I can still close the Command Prompt window though). I am trying to change the database path because right now it defaults to `C:/data/db` even though Mongo is installed on a foreign Disk Drive. I have tried running both commands as a System Administrator to no avail. Any ideas as to I can solve this issue?

Comment: In another terminal/command prompt, try connecting to that instance of database you are running.

Comment: @Yahya 
When I run "mongod" with the "config" or "dbpath" command running in the background, I recieve an error code 100. This is due to "mongod" searching for "C:/data/db" which I did not create because I want MongoDB to use "F:/data/db". "F:/data/db is the path I tried to set with the "config" or "dbpath" command, which stalls when I run it.

Comment: @Yahya 
A partial solution I found was to navigate to the F: drive and run "mongod" from there. I still can't change the dbpath however it now looks for "F:/data/db". Not a full fix to the problem, but at least I can use MongoDB.

Comment: You need to launch mongod from config file. And you will need to define the dbpath and logpath in that config file. And since you will be running it from command prompt, make sure you keep it running. As soon as you close it, it will stop.